# Python filter nested dict given list of key names

Tags: python, recursion

Is there a way to filter a nested dict in Python, so I can see only the keys I'd specified ?
Example:

```
x = {
  "field": [
    {
      "nm_field": "ch_origem_sistema_chave",
      "inf_tabelado": {
        "dropdown_value": "",
        "dropdown_key": "",
        "url_lista": "",
        "chave_relacional": ""
      },
    },
    {
      "nm_field": "ax_andamento_data",
      "inf_tabelado": {
        "dropdown_value": "",
        "dropdown_key": "",
        "url_lista": "",
        "chave_relacional": ""
      },
    }
  ],
  "_metadata": {
    "dt_reg": "22/01/2014 16:17:16",
    "dt_last_up": "10/04/2014 16:30:44",
  },
  "url_detalhes": "/DetalhesDocsPro.aspx",
  "url_app": "/docspro",
}

y = filter(x, ['dropdown_value', 'nm_field', 'url_app', 'dt_reg'])
```

Then var y would be something like:

```
{
  "field": [
    {
      "nm_field": "ch_origem_sistema_chave",
      "inf_tabelado": {
        "dropdown_value": "",
      },
    },
    {
      "nm_field": "ax_andamento_data",
      "inf_tabelado": {
        "dropdown_value": "",
      },
    }
  ],
  "_metadata": {
    "dt_reg": "22/01/2014 16:17:16",
  },
  "url_app": "/docspro",
}
```

I've tried to do something using defaultdict, but had no success with lists at any level of recursion. Also I found dificulty while working with different data structures.

Comment: So let me get this straight - you're basically taking a tree structure and pruning it?

Comment: @2rs2ts Yes, I think ..

Comment: Are you guaranteed to only have lists and dictionaries?

Comment: yes, and also key names will not repeat (except if they're in list structures)

Comment: Why are field, url_app and _metadata in the output but not url_detalhes?

Comment: Is it possible for `None` to ever be a key in one of the dictionaries?

Comment: @shaktimaan `url_detalhes` was not in the list of key strings nor was it a data structure which contained one of those strings.

Comment: @user1538560 So what should the output be if you took `"dropdown_value"` out of the list? Should `"inf_tabelado"` be an empty dictionary or should it be removed?

Comment: @2rs2ts In this case, should be removed

Comment: @RobWatts No, None will never be a key

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a modified version of 2rs2ts's answer that returns a new object rather than modifying the old one (and handles filtering on non-leaf nodes):

```
import copy

def fltr(node, vals):
    if isinstance(node, dict):
        retVal = {}
        for key in node:
            if key in vals:
                retVal[key] = copy.deepcopy(node[key])
            elif isinstance(node[key], list) or isinstance(node[key], dict):
                child = fltr(node[key], vals)
                if child:
                    retVal[key] = child
        if retVal:
             return retVal
        else:
             return None
    elif isinstance(node, list):
        retVal = []
        for entry in node:
            child = fltr(entry, vals)
            if child:
                retVal.append(child)
        if retVal:
            return retVal
        else:
            return None
```

With this, you will call

```
y = fltr(x, ['dropdown_value', 'nm_field', 'url_app', 'dt_reg'])
```

and get

```
{
    "field": [
        {
            "inf_tabelado": {
                "dropdown_value": ""
            },
            "nm_field": "ch_origem_sistema_chave"
        },
        {
            "inf_tabelado": {
                "dropdown_value": ""
            },
            "nm_field": "ax_andamento_data"
        }
    ],
    "url_app": "/docspro",
    "_metadata": {
        "dt_reg": "22/01/2014 16:17:16"
    }
}
```

Note that this will return `None` if everything is filtered. For example,

```
fltr(x, [])
```

will always return `None`, no matter what is in `x`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution which walks the structure in a depth-first manner to find the "leaf" nodes which you are checking to see if they're in your list of elements to preserve. When it finds such an element, it removes it from the dictionary with `del`. (So this is done in-place.)

```
def fltr(d, vals):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        vals_to_del = []
        for k in d:
            if k in vals:
                continue
            if not isinstance(d[k], list) and not isinstance(d[k], dict):
                if k not in vals:
                    vals_to_del.append(k)
            else:
                fltr(d[k], vals)
        for k in vals_to_del:
            del d[k]
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for i in d:
            fltr(i, vals)
```

Note that I didn't define a function called `filter`, because it's a built-in one and you don't want to shadow it.

```
>>> fltr(x, ['dropdown_value', 'nm_field', 'url_app', 'dt_reg'])
>>> x
{'field': [{'inf_tabelado': {'dropdown_value': ''}, 'nm_field': 'ch_origem_sistema_chave'}, {'inf_tabelado': {'dropdown_value': ''}, 'nm_field': 'ax_andamento_data'}], 'url_app': '/docspro', '_metadata': {'dt_reg': '22/01/2014 16:17:16'}}
```

Comment: This is good, but the solution must work not only for leaves, but to any node at the tree.

Comment: @user1538560 argh, I made that realization but forgot to update my answer! Looks like Rob took care of it, so that's good.